# Jetty stable releases

Tags: jetty, release

How to find list of stable releases for Jetty server? I've checked in [github](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/releases)
and [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server) but still not able to find if its a stable release.

I am getting this warning :

INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.12.RC2;
WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - THIS IS NOT A STABLE RELEASE! DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version "9.4.12.RC2" is a non-final / unstable release.

Some examples of non-final / unstable release keywords found in version strings in the 20 year history of Jetty.

- "RC2" - Release Candidate 2
- "M1" - Milestone 1
- "SNAPSHOT" - A snapshot of a specific build
- "Beta"
- "Alpha"
- "Experimental"

There are 2 different version strings you should be looking for.

- `<servlet_support>.<major>.<minor>.v<year><month><day>` : Extremely Common - this is a historical versioning syntax as seen with Eclipse OSGi, and something that Eclipse Jetty adopted.  (eg: `9.4.12.v20180830`)
- `<servlet_support>.<major>.<minor>` : Rare - but Jetty will be going back to this shorter form starting in Jetty 10.0 (still many months out)

Note that Jetty versioning has always used the first version to indicate the Servlet support, the second part is the Major version within that Servlet support.

Eg:

- `7` is Servlet 2.5
- `8` is Servlet 3.0
- `9` is Servlet 3.1
- `10` is Servlet 4.0 (from the new Jakarta EE project)

The documentation has general advice seen at :

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

The official downloads page always lists the current stable release as well :

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

One final note, don't use mvnrepository.com it's very out of date and often wrong.

Use search.maven.org for the most accurate and up to date information.

Example, if you had used search.maven.org you would have seen what's newer then `9.4.12.RC2`

https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.jetty%20AND%20a:jetty-home&core=gav

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info.